# How to login to JupyterHub directly through URL by Providing either Token alone or Username and Password

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, oauth, jupyterhub

I have an application and want to incorporate JupyterHub in my application. I Want to access JupyterHub home page directly using URL without Logging manually in Browser.

I tried adding following lines in jupyterhub_config.py
**c.Authenticator.enable_auth_state = True**
but still it is redirecting to the Login Page.

I want to Directly access the Home page using URL.